# Как сделать вот такую вот активность?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Эту "feature" я вижу очень часто в android приложениях. Как ее реализовать?
Использую Android Studio последнюю версию.

Вот скриншот:

[image: Пример в приложениях]

Comment: Все работает вызываю  ProgressDialog myDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Загружаю сервера","Подождите немного...", true);

Comment: Но если я его осталвяю в onCreate а потом сделаю процесс, то myDialog не отобразится, отобразится когда закончится процесс, а если myDialog.dismiss(); в конце поставить то я не увижу как сделать чтобы он отображался и когда закончится процесс заканчивался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта штука зовется [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)